# Are these integrals convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Recently I've come across two integrals that seemed hard to check for me. Here they are:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x \sin \ln x}{x^2 + \cos x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
And another:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin \ln x}{(\ln x)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I've already figured out how to prove the first one's convergence upon $\int_0^e$, but have no proper ideas to let me proceed to infinity as applying equivalence is restricted by sign changes of sinus. But I'm convinced they both diverge :)
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the asymptotics as $x\rightarrow \infty$ on the first integral

\begin{equation}
\frac{x\sin(\ln(x))}{x^2+\cos(x)}
\sim
\frac{x\sin(\ln(x))}{x^2}
=
\frac{\sin(\ln(x))}{x}
\end{equation}

If we change variables

\begin{equation}
\int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\ln(x))}{x} dx
=
\int_{\ln(N)}^{\infty} \sin(u) du
\end{equation}

For the second integral, use a change of variables

\begin{equation}
\int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\ln(x))}{(\ln(x))^3} dx
=
\int_{\ln(N)}^{\infty} \frac{e^{u}}{u^3}\sin(u)du
\end{equation}

It seems that both diverge, but this is all imprecise. The details would need to be filled in. If you restrict to intervals of the form $[e^{\pi M},e^{\pi M+\pi}]$, then the sign in the numerator with be either positive or negative and you can make the necessary comparisons.

Comment: your reply is much appreciated :)